Lacking intuition regarding angular velocities
I am aware of the definition :-
$$ \omega_{A/B}=\omega_{A/G}-\omega_{B/G}$$
where /G signifies angular velocity relative to ground or a reference frame at rest.
But I am unable to understand it intuitively I did look on the internet but I did not find anything on why it was defined this way , I have a little trouble with the definition of relative translation velocity as well. I looked for similar question and I did find this but I am simply unable to see why it would be defined that way like how do I get to this definition from ground up using the fact $\omega = \dfrac{d\theta}{dt}$ and understand it intuitively, I do however have a vague understanding like you know A rotated 60 deg and B rotated 30 deg so both of these would have a combined effect leaving the perception for B that A rotated 90 degrees. But I do not really feel it and is not a very clear picture for me at least, any additional resources would also be highly appreciated.
Edit
Someone suggested me this Relative angular velocity and acceleration
but I can follow along the math, I am facing problem is in how do you visualise and understand it conceptually and intuitively. Especially even thinking of a roatating rigid rod makes me dizzy.

Try drawing two concentric rings, each one with a point particle traveling along it. Assume they start from the same angle relative to the common center, and look at what happens if you let each one move for some time slice $\Delta t$ along respective angles $\Delta \theta_1$ and $\Delta \theta_2$

@Farcher I had a look , the answers were more along mathematical lines. I am aware of these , i am looking for a more intuitive exlanation that gives feel to the bones.

If you want to visualise what is happening with limited maths then you probably need to confine yourself to simple examples, eg the two crossing axes at right angles to one anorther.

Acquiring "intuition" is the result of working through the physics and math enough times that you can see the way to get through more easily. And, ultimately, the end result is that your intuition is different than mine.

Think of an example of a rotating object placed on the top of another rotating object (rotating about the same axis.) E.g., a child standing in the center of a roundabout/merry-go-round/carousel. Let us consider there situations:

At first carousel doesn't move, but the child rotates about their own axis with angular velocity $\omega_{A/B}$.
Now, let carousel rotate with angular velocity $\omega_{B/G}$, while the child doesn't move (in respect to the carousel).
Now we combine both movements: the carousel rotates, while the child also rotates, so that their rotation in respect to the ground is even faster.

A more grown-up example could be thinking of an airplane flying along a parallel with angular velocity $\omega_{A/B}=v/R$, where $v$ is its speed in respect to the ground. The Earth itself rotates about its axis, so the overall angular speed of the airplane is the sum of the two.

I also think of it in almost the same manner I am rotating with resepct to A at 60 deg per min but A himself is rotating at 30 deg per min with respect to ground. so it is a boost and with respect to ground I am rotating 90 deg per min. But for me it brings up 2 questions :-
a) From here the subtraction eqn is just rearragement of terms but how can we think of the subtraction form on itself without thinking of "boosts" or addition.
b) It seems to be more of a memory tool to me like yeah it is fairly intuitive but it is nw lacking rigour like there is a feeling but why add?
